# I can't stop my "program" to a specific print, it just goes on

Tags: python

There is an issue I'm having, it's a small story I'm, this has been frustrating me for hours now, help me!

```
if qsg_1 == "A":
    print ("Amazing, let's begin...")
elif qsg_1 == "B":
    print ("Goodbye, sinner.")

print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print("A tree is behind you.")
```

This seemed fine to me, but whenever I went and chose option B after opening the .py, this happened:

```
Okay user. Would you like to start this amazing journey?
[A] No. [B] Yes. [A/B]: B
Goodbye, sinner.
.
.
.
.
.
.
A tree is behind you.
```

I want to stop the "elif qsg_1 == "B": to print ("Goodbye, sinner.").
I have tried to, although it's as if B was A, so even the:

```
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print(".")
print("A tree is behind you.")
```

appears, which has been getting me for hours now, I want the B option to end at print ("Goodbye, sinner") whenever I choose it, how do I do that? Help!

Comment: Hi there. The code behaves exactly like it's supposed to. It checks your input and prints one of two options depending on the input. And after that, it continues with the program. If you want the program to stop when option B is chosen, you have to tell it to, like with "sys.exit(0)"

Comment: It would be helpful if you post all your code, a running script, so that people can run it and give feedback.

Comment: It isn’t clear to me what the issues. Looking at the accepted answer, it’s just a matter of not understanding the flow of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses indentation to control what gets executed when. Consider the following:

```
if qsg_1 == "A":
    print ("Amazing, let's begin...")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print("A tree is behind you.")
elif qsg_1 == "B":
    print ("Goodbye, sinner.")
```

Here, many `print` statements are under condition A, indented, so it is a good visual way to show what happens if condition A holds. The same for B.

Answer (score 2):

Put you code to function and add `return` after printing `B` case

```
def my_fn():
    if qsg_1 == "A":
        print ("Amazing, let's begin...")
    elif qsg_1 == "B":
        print ("Goodbye, sinner.")
        return

    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print(".")
    print("A tree is behind you.")


my_fn()
```

Comment: Although it's a pretty valid answer, it's clear that the author lacks the fundamentals of programming, so I don't think this is the best approach for this question

Comment: This is also a good answer, but he might need to pass a parameter in with the value of qsg_1. `def my_fn(qsg_1):`